# Xcode Archive linker error. Static libs created in Debug-iphonos directory

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive

I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 to create an archive for iTunes submission and I get a linker error. I discovered that the reason behind it is that the static libraries created by my sub-projects are created in the build\Debug-iphoneos directory rather than Release-iphoneos. In the Product->Edit Scheme dialog I confirmed that the sub-projects Archive schemes all have the "Release" build configuration set and have "Reveal Archive in Organizer" checked. Also, my main project has Skip Install set to YES and the Target Skip Install is set to NO. All sub projects have Skip Install to YES. So I conclude that the Archive scheme for the sub projects are likely not being invoked by the main project when I Product->Archive it. I have looked at many settings and don't have a clue?

Thanks....

Comment: I was able to solve this by Archiving the static libs first, which produced the correct Release version, then Archiving the main project which was able to link them in..Hope this helps someone out...